# Why is the Amazon FSx ARN for resource selection in AWS Backup different than every other service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-backup, amazon-fsx

I'm trying to create an AWS backup plan resource selection for resources in my given region.  Usually this is pretty straightforward if you've seen ARNs before.  Most of them look like this:

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:*
```

When I try to do that for FSx, I get an error message about the format being wrong.
What I tried:

```
arn:aws:fsx:us-east-2:*
```

Error message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateBackupSelection operation: Invalid resource selection: 'arn:aws:fsx:us-east-2:*'. Expected string format: arn:<partition>:fsx:*.
```

Can I not limit this resource selection to my given region?  What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Your code;

```
arn:aws:fsx:us-east-2:*
```

Required Format for FSx;

```
arn:aws:fsx:${Region}:${Account}:${ResourceType}/${ResourcePath}
```

i.e.

```
arn:aws:fsx:us-east-2:111122223333:file-system/fs-0123abcd56789ef0a
```

So just put the correct Region and Account Number into the ARN and the last bit would just be the *

Comment: Doing `"arn:aws:fsx:us-east-2:myaccount#:*"` also does not work with the error: `Specified 'fsx' resource is not supported by AWS Backup.`

Comment: Given that, just contact AWS Support. It's their platform. Get them to tell you the answer. The above answer is based on the official AWS documentation which are at best on a good day crappy. It is what it is.